# mongodb C# query doesn't respond

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get Item from mongodb Server, sometimes its work and after 4-5 attemps its stop resonding in the last row (I can't take out the object out side the query)
any one had it before? what is the right way to take out the object?

```
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("myPlaces");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<MongoPlace>("Places");  
            int startDay =  int.Parse(Request.QueryString["day"]);
            MongoPlace mp = collection.AsQueryable<MongoPlace>().Where(x => x.guid == 
                            Request.QueryString["id"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're hitting the default connection pool limit.

As it looks like this is a web application, you shouldn't be opening the client more than once per instance of your web application.

The `MongoClient`, `MongoServer`,  `MongoDatabase` and `MongoCollection` are all thread-safe and generally there should only be one instance of each. (See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) for more information).

You'd probably want to do this as the application starts and then maintain the connections statically until the application exits.

In my ASP.NET MVC applications, I usually add a "DatabaseConfig" class that's called in the same way as other app configurations. As an example here's some code I've got in the project I'm currently building using MongoDB (there isn't any error handling yet):

```
var client = new MongoClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();

DataLayer.Client = client;
DataLayer.Server = server;

var settings = new MongoDatabaseSettings(server, "default");            
settings.WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged;
DataLayer.Database = DataLayer.GetDatabase(settings);
```

Then, in Application_Start, I call an `Initialize` method that contains the code above.

```
DatabaseConfig.Initialize();
```